# Unresolved dependency hamcrest-core in SBT build

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I'm trying to build the Scala hello world example for the Play framework: https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial

I'm getting this unresolved dependency:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3: org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3!hamcrest-core.pom(pom.original) origin location must be absolute: file:/home/sahandz/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3 (/home/sahandz/comdev/play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/build.sbt#L12-13)
[warn]        +- junit:junit:4.12
[warn]        +- com.typesafe.play:play-test_2.13:2.7.3 ((play.sbt.PlaySettings.serviceSettings) PlaySettings.scala#L67)
[warn]        +- org.scalatestplus.play:scalatestplus-play_2.13:4.0.3 (/home/sahandz/comdev/play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/build.sbt#L11-12)
[warn]        +- com.example:play-scala-seed_2.13:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Here is the build.sbt-file:

```
name := """play-scala-seed"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"  // Previously: 2.13.0

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.3" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-core" % "1.3" % Test
```

I've changed the scala version to be the same as the one on my machine:

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL
```

My SBT version is:

```
$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] 1.2.8
```

My Java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.10.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

And my Maven version (if it is relevant):

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

How does this error occur? I've looked in the maven repository and it seems like the artifact exists, although it is deprecated: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3

Comment: To help future readers, you can answer your own question and accept it. it will be easier to find than your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by going into the `~/.ivy2` folder and deleting `jars/org.hamcrest_hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and `cache/org.hamcrest/`. Any explanations as to why this worked are appreciated.